# How to change the atheros wireless driver on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers

The driver installed by windows automatically just caused a blue screen by me. I read that I need to install the driver from the manufacturer. I downloaded it from here: https://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-download.php?chipset=37&system=6 It is a zip with .sys and .cat files which I don't know how to install. On top of that by removing the previous driver and clicking on find hardware changes the system automatically installs the buggy one. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have this problem with my Atheros-based WiFi card, but in my case, "Install from Custom Location" didn't work. What did work, however, is the following:

1- Right-click the card in Device Manager and click Update Driver Software
2- Select the second option: "Browse my computer for driver software"
3- Click "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
4- Click the "Have disk..." button and select the location of the downloaded/unzipped files.
5- Proceed.

Comment: As I already wrote. :-) But does not matter I rather give points to sy than accepting my own answer.